# Remove string between two different delimiters

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Want to eliminate numbers and preceding colons when numbers are contained between a colon and a comma.

my example text (real data is much larger):

```
(fa___537:50.0,(fa___542:100.0,((
```

desired output:

```
(fa___537,(fa___542,((
```

My unfortunate try

```
sed -i 's/\:....\,/\,/g' myfile
```

Comment: simple enough to do for given sample, what have you tried? search for `:` followed by sequence of numbers/dot and ending with `,` then replace all such patterns with `,`

Comment: this is an example of a much larger text. I would like to do it with sed

Comment: if this example is not representative of your real case, then add more examples to the question or modify the one you've given... whichever tool you prefer, give it a shot and show your effort to solve it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will work:

```
sed -i 's/:[0-9]*\.[0-9]*,/,/g' YourFile
```

Comment: Actually the [0-9]* are well within their rights to match nothing and hence a combo like `:., => ,`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated version which is considerably simplified based on S.C.'s inputs:

```
sed -e '
   s/[:][0-9]\{1,\}[.]\{0,1\}[0-9]*[,]/\
/g
   s/[:][.][0-9]\{1,\}[,]/\
/g
   y/\n/,/
'
```

Comment: You are right I didn't foresee that combination. I am placing an edited version which is reasonably water tight.